# Hanning and Hamming window functions in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, audio

I'm trying to implement [Hanning and Hamming window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Window_examples) in C#. I can't find any .Net samples anywhere and I'm not sure if my attempts at converting from C++ samples does the job well.

My problem is mainly that looking at the [formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_window) I imagine they need to have the original number somewhere on the right hand side of the equation - I just don't get it from looking at the formulas. (My math isn't that good yet obviously.)

What I have so far:

```
public Complex[] Hamming(Complex[] iwv)
{
    Complex[] owv = new Complex[iwv.Length];
    double omega = 2.0 * Math.PI / (iwv.Length);

    // owv[i].Re = real number (raw wave data)
    // owv[i].Im = imaginary number (0 since it hasn't gone through FFT yet)
    for (int i = 1; i < owv.Length; i++)
        // Translated from c++ sample I found somewhere
        owv[i].Re = (0.54 - 0.46 * Math.Cos(omega * (i))) * iwv[i].Re; 

    return owv;

}

public Complex[] Hanning(Complex[] iwv)
{
    Complex[] owv = new Complex[iwv.Length];
    double omega = 2.0 * Math.PI / (iwv.Length);

    for (int i = 1; i < owv.Length; i++)
        owv[i].Re = (0.5  + (1 - Math.Cos((2d * Math.PI ) / (i -1)))); // Uhm... wrong

    return owv;
}
```

Comment: Check out your loops - it simple skip first element in array 'owv[0]'. It must be: for (int i = 0; i < owv.Length; i++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a [Hamming window in use](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f652f98eb1ff#VoiceRecorder.Audio/FftPitchDetector.cs) in an open source C# application I wrote a while back. It's being used in a pitch detector for an [autotune effect](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/AutotuneNET).

Comment: Thanks. I've posted my results in my blog: http://blog.tedd.no/2011/07/15/hanning-hamming-window-functions-in-c/

Comment: One quick performance improvement you can use is to pre-calculate the window coefficients for every value of n, since that usually doesn't change during the lifetime of an application, and calls to Math.Sin/Cos are relatively slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Math.NET library.

```
    double[] hannDoubles = MathNet.Numerics.Window.Hamming(dataIn.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataIn.Length; i++)
    {
        dataOut[i] = hannDoubles[i] * dataIn[i];
    }
```

See my answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939606/246758

Answer (score 0):

The operation of "windowing" means multiplying a signal by a window function.  This code you found appears to generate the window function and scale the original signal.  The equations are for just the window function itself, not the scaling.